# Missing import suggestion for Generic class type

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

Please see the below screen shot taken from the Eclipse Java IDE:

[image: Eclipse Quick Fix Suggestion]

Why doesn't Eclipse suggest importing `BigInteger` from `java.math.BigInteger`? The import suggestion for `BigInteger` appears only after importing `java.util.List`.

Could somebody explain the reason behind this?

**UPDATE**:

To check if the below answer is the reason, I tried this. I created a custom `class Test<T extends MyClass>` and checked the suggestions for the below code. The screen shot is as shown below:

[image: Eclipse Quick Fix Suggestion]

Obviously, `java.math.BigInteger` is not a valid candidate for import. Eclipse still suggests it. This confirms that in earlier case, Eclipse is not holding the import suggestion for `BigInteger` to filter valid classes for import.

Comment: What happens when you mouse over `List`? It probably says "List cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Import java util List, then it will show the correct suggestions for BigInteger...

Comment: @JonnyHenly - Moving mouse over both `List` and `ArrayList` suggests imports. I would like to understand the reason why `BigInteger` import is suggested only after importing `List`. I mean why the `BigInteger` import cannot be or should not be suggested first?

Comment: @ppeterka - Yes, it works that way. But I would like to know what's wrong in providing a import suggestion for `BigInteger` or why it cannot be?

Comment: It sounds like an aspect of the parser that is used by Eclipse.  It sees `List` not existing so it flags that first and doesn't check the type because you couldn't create the object you want to attribute the type to.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main reasoning behind this is that Eclipse doesn't know what `List`'s *class signature* (for lack of better words) is. Since you haven't imported `java.util.List` then `List` could be anything. For instance, you could have your own `List` class, in another package, declared as:

```
public class List<T extends Double> { ... }
```

Or something similar.

In which case I don't think Eclipse wants to guess at which class is a valid type parameter until it knows which `List` you're importing.

**Addressing Your Update:**

If anything your update seems to prove what the user Susannah Potts said in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880838/missing-import-suggestion-for-generic-class-type/38881102?noredirect=1#comment65123242_38880838):

> It sounds like an aspect of the parser that is used by Eclipse. It sees `List` not existing so it flags that first and doesn't check the type because you couldn't create the object you want to attribute the type to.

Also you state:

> Obviously, `java.math.BigInteger` is not a valid candidate for import. Eclipse still suggests it. This confirms that in earlier case, Eclipse is not holding the import suggestion for `BigInteger` to filter valid classes for import.

Your update doesn't exactly confirm what you suggest. Eclipse could be designed to list all classes which match a given name, when a valid class does not exist. For instance the only `BigInteger` class is `java.math.BigInteger`, perhaps if you had your own custom `BigInteger extends MyClass`, in another package in the build path, then Eclipse would only suggest that `BigInteger` class, or suggest it before `java.math.BigInteger`.

**The Real Answer:**

Basically anything could be happening, there might even be a cache of most used classes that Eclipse looks at. There are also multiple versions of Eclipse and each could exhibit different behavior. The only way to get a valid answer is if you contact the creators of the version of Eclipse that you're using and ask them.

Comment: Makes sense. But, still am not convinced. After all, it's going to be a suggestion and it's up to the developer to act upon. Are you trying to say **Eclipse can suggest imports but it doesn't because of reasons in your post**?

Comment: @jnanthak Kind of. I'm saying it would be a lot of  *extra* work for Eclipse to find every `BigInteger` class and compare each with every possible `List` class with a type parameter that accepts `BigInteger`. It makes more sense for the programmer to specify the class before Eclipse suggests (or does work to find) valid candidates for the type parameter.

Comment: I've updated my post. I think Eclipse is not holding the import suggestion to show the valid type parameter.